# A criterion for non-orientability of a 3-manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

A compact surface is nonorientable if and only if it contains an embedded Mobius strip.  I am wondering to what extent this result extends to higher dimensions - I suspect the answer is not at all.

Let $N^3$ be a closed nonorientable 3-manifold.  Does there exist an embedded closed orientable surface $F \subset N$ so that the normal bundle of $F$ in $N$ is not trivial?

Answer (score 2):

If $N$ is a nonorientable $3$-manifold, then there is a closed loop $\gamma\subset N$ that represents the nonorientability of $N$.  This means that if you were to carry a nonzero element of $\bigwedge^3TN$ around this loop, it would change sign after its journey.

A closed regular neighborhood $\overline{\nu(\gamma)}$ of $\gamma$ is a twisted $D^2$ bundle over $S^1$.  The boundary of this is an embedded Klein bottle $K$, so $N$ indeed has a closed nonorientable $2$-dimensional submanifold.  However, $K$ is a two-sided surface by construction (that is, its normal bundle is trivial).

But, this is fine, and its converse is true:  if $N$ is a $3$-manifold with an embedded nonorientable two-sided compact surface $S$, then $N$ is nonorientable.  Take a loop $\gamma$ representing the nonorientability of $S$, which is a loop whose normal bundle in $S$ is a Mobius strip $M\subset S$.  The product $M\times [-1,1]\subset N$ is not orientable, so neither is $N$.  In fact, $\gamma$ gives an embedded Klein bottle like before.

Thus we have the following characterization: $N$ is a nonorientable $3$-manifold iff $N$ has an embedded two-sided Klein bottle.

Two-sidedness of the Klein bottle is important.  The twisted $S^1$-bundle $S^1\mathbin{\tilde{\times}} S^1 \mathbin{\tilde{\times}} S^1$ over the Klein bottle is a closed orientable $3$-manifold, but its Klein bottle is one-sided.

Comment: The twisted $D^2$ bundle over $S^1$ has its own name, a solid Klein bottle, in analogy to a solid torus. So you can also say that nonorientable 3-manifolds are characterized by existence of a subspace homeomorphic to the solid Klein bottle, which seems a somewhat closer analogue to the 2-dimensional case.

Comment: Heyo Kyle - this is great but imma leave this up since I'm still interested in the stated question.  I'm guessing that argument generalizes to all dimensions, for example in 4D, "if you have an embedded "one-sided" non-orientable sumanifold, then you are nonorientble".  Here your nonorientable submanifold has a solid Klein bottle (for lack of a better name) $B$, by what you said, and this has trivial normal bundle so is $B \times [-1,1]$ equal to the "solid $S^1 \times S^2$" - thus giving our nonoriented loop?